# Asp.net Core 2.0 always receives 404 once deployed

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.Net Core API that works great while running in Visual Studio.  I am able to perform all actions successfully.  However, now that I have deployed it to a Win 2008 R2 server, using IIS as reverse proxy, no page resolves.  I always get a 404 page not found error.  Actually, if I add a default get method returning value array, like what is provided by default when creating a new controller, it always returns.  I do not understand what the issue is.

Comment: Have you installed [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle](https://aka.ms/dotnetcore-2-windowshosting) on win 2008 R2 server?

Comment: What is your rout preferences? Can you add a copy of `Startup` class?

Comment: Yes, Duran, I have installed the .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle

Comment: Afshar, I am using Attribute routing.  I am only using a "route" attribute on the controller.  I am providing all action routes as rest verbs, for example "[HttpGet("{Id:Guid}")].  Remember, this works perfectly in my local environment on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the given information, I suspect only one thing, is that your server is not allowing HTTP Methods, or at least the OPTIONS one(for the preflight request).

To remediate to that, check out the UrlScan.ini config file in your server located at the below path:

**C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\urlscan**

Open the file, and go to [AllowVerbs] section, it should be as the following(Add OPTIONS if it's not there):

```
[AllowVerbs]

;
; The verbs (aka HTTP methods) listed here are those commonly
; processed by a typical IIS server.
;
; Note that these entries are effective if "UseAllowVerbs=1"
; is set in the [Options] section above.
;

GET
HEAD
POST
OPTIONS
```

Hope you'll find this useful

Comment: Sorry, it has been a while, but I have moved on from this.  However, I will give credit.